# Clear Text Overlay using opencv

Tags: text, opencv, overlay

i was wondering if there is a way to clear a text overlay using opencv. i nee to write text to the same area of the screen and it just writes over the initial overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a white rectangle at the place you want to write text.

```
cv::rectangle(image,topLeftPoint,bottomRightPoint,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED);
```